# Drag & Drop a image via jQuery to get image dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, native, dimensions

I using [jquery-filedrop](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop) and i allowed user to upload file only PNG & JPG

But how can I check image size (like pixel) ?

**Possible to get image size in file object ?**

After I looked at the file object in console.log , it's nothing about image size.

[image]

[image]

Or I have to check in PHP or append image so `.width()` & `.height()` [(REF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I post like this to PHP

```
$size = getimagesize($_FILES['name']['tmp_name']);

    if($size[0]===150 && $size[1]===150) {
       // done
    } else {
       // error
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1093364/1437016) of [Georg Schölly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24587/georg-scholly):

```
// find the element
var img = $('#imageid');

/* 
 * create an offscreen image that isn't scaled
 * but contains the same image.
 * Because it's cached it should be instantly here.
 */

var theImage = new Image();
theImage.src = img.attr("src");

// you should check here if the image has finished loading
// this can be done with theImage.complete

alert("Width: " + theImage.width);
alert("Height: " + theImage.height);
```