# Pictures on my web application aren't in their real size

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb.net, web-applications

So I have I project, where I have a lot of picture of brackets and I have to show them according to their reference.
The problem is that they have to be scaled (1/1) because size is an important detail for the project.
My question is how to display the images in their 1/1 dimension on a 10" tablet when I know their dimensions and resolutions.

I am using Microsoft Visual 2010 web developer for the development (html, css, js and VB.net)
I already tried the max-width= 100% .

Comment: Duplicate: [Detecting the system DPI/PPI from JS/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279749/detecting-the-system-dpi-ppi-from-js-css)

Comment: Btw, the short answer is that can actually do `<img src="..." style="width: 8in">` (or `12cm` or whatever)

Comment: the CSS property `max-width= 100%` applies the width of the parent. Why don't you just set your image width and height to their real pixel size ?

Comment: @E-telier That would only work if the image resolution was the same as the device display's resolution. That's not the case though, as you can see in the [px per inch column here](https://screensiz.es/).

Comment: @E-telier this will only work for one image, but i have like 1200 with different resolutions

Comment: @Azii0803 Your server could probably do that for you, but in case it can't you could use `img.naturalWidth` and `img.naturalHeight` (see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093137/can-javascript-access-native-image-size)